# Cannot add logging handlers for Thespian Actors

Tags: python, logging, actor

Trying to set up parallelization in Thespian (Actor-Model system), however, I am getting an error and there is 0 documentation or resources on how to solve it.

```
class Init:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Test(ActorTypeDispatcher):
    ...

class FooBar(ActorTypeDispatcher):
    def receiveMsg_Init(self, message, sender):
        self.createActor(Test)

class actorLogFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, logrecord):
        return 'actorAddress' in logrecord.__dict__


class notActorLogFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, logrecord):
        return 'actorAddress' not in logrecord.__dict__

logcfg = {'version': 1,
          'formatters': {
              'normal': {'format': '%(levelname)-8s %(message)s'},
              'actor': {'format': '%(levelname)-8s %(actorAddress)s => %(message)s'}},
          'filters': {'isActorLog': {'()': actorLogFilter},
                      'notActorLog': {'()': notActorLogFilter}},
          'handlers': {'h1': {'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
                              'filename': 'example.log',
                              'formatter': 'normal',
                              'filters': ['notActorLog'],
                              'level': logging.INFO},
                       'h2': {'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
                              'filename': 'example.log',
                              'formatter': 'actor',
                              'filters': ['isActorLog'],
                              'level': logging.INFO}, },
          'loggers': {'': {'handlers': ['h1', 'h2'], 'level': logging.DEBUG}}
}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    system = ActorSystem("multiprocQueueBase", logDefs=logcfg)
    main = system.createActor(FooBar)
    system.tell(main, Init())
```

Error

```
ERROR  ActorAddr-Q.ThespianQ.b => Actor __main__.Main @ ActorAddr-Q.ThespianQ.b retryable exception on message <definitions.Init object at 0x7f9c82283af0>
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/logging/config.py", line 642, in configure
    self.configure_root(root)

  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/logging/config.py", line 802, in configure_root
    self.common_logger_config(root, config, incremental)

  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/logging/config.py", line 783, in common_logger_config
    logger.removeHandler(h)

  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/thespian/system/logdirector.py", line 183, in removeHandler
    raise NotImplementedError('Cannot add logging handlers for Thespian Actors')

NotImplementedError: Cannot add logging handlers for Thespian Actors

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/thespian/system/actorManager.py", line 164, in _handleOneMessage
    actor_result = self.actorInst.receiveMessage(msg, envelope.sender)

  File "main.py", line 98, in receiveMessage
    self.init()

  File "main.py", line 60, in init
    a = elf.createActor(Test)

  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/thespian/actors.py", line 637, in __init__
    systemBase = self._startupActorSys(

  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/thespian/actors.py", line 662, in _startupActorSys
    systemBase = thespian.system \

  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/thespian/system/simpleSystemBase.py", line 257, in __init__
    if logDefs is not False: dictConfig(logDefs or defaultLoggingConfig)

  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/logging/config.py", line 808, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()

  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/logging/config.py", line 644, in configure
    raise ValueError('Unable to configure root '

ValueError: Unable to configure root logger
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sample code is incomplete in some manner (i.e. not a complete representation of the code encountering the error): there are probably some logging calls that are not shown.  The `NotImplementedError` you are encountering is due to an attempt to call `logging.addHandler()` or `logging.removeHandler()`, which are not supported for Actors themselves because the logging support in Thespian provides specific handlers.  The logging in Thespian should be initialized via the `logDefs` argument to the `ActorSystem()` call (see https://thespianpy.com/doc/using.html#hH-ce55494c-dd7a-4258-a1e8-b090c3bbb1e6).

Comment: Updated my answer to include logDefs, but still getting same error

Comment: You've added the Thespian logging initialization, but there is still something (not shown in your example code: that runs with no errors for me) which is running in one or more of your Actors that is trying to call `logging.addHandler()` or `logging.removeHandler()`.  Those calls are not supported when done from within an Actor.